# Finding Bitmap image filename in C#

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface, bitmap, resources

I have a 52 sized Bitmap array that each cell contains a random image from the resources. I want to figure out what is the name of the chosen image and when I try to debug the program, "cards[i]" equals to: "{System.Drawing.Bitmap}".

How can I find the name of the image that cards[i] equals to?

```
private Bitmap[] GetResourceImages()
{
    PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(Properties.Resources).GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            var images = props.Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(Bitmap)).Select(prop => prop.GetValue(null, null) as Bitmap).ToArray();

            return images;
}

Bitmap[] cards = GetResourceImages();
int maxValue = cards.Length;
Random rand = new Random();
int idx = rand.Next(maxValue);
currentPic.Image = cards[idx];
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the C programming language?

Comment: Save that information at the time you choose them.

Comment: Well, you are not retrieving a string, but rather the bitmap.  You are looking for PropertyType = Bitmap...  so really you want to return an array of classed with the path value, or a dictionary.  I'd go through each property, find the answer, and do something with it.. read your code, understand it.  Hint: Bitmap[] is not the answer you are after.

Comment: Bitmaps contain no info about their source.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right way by going through the properties, but if you fetch the property's value you obviously end up with the bitmap, and not the name.

The actual original filename is completely lost, though; there is no way to retrieve information that is not saved in your program. The closest you can come is retrieving the property name. This means that you should be looking at `prop.Name` instead of `prop.GetValue(...)`.

You could of course simply retrieve *both*, either in a separate array, or in something like a dictionary. Here I just give it as an output array to the function.

```
private Bitmap[] GetResourceImages(out String[] names)
{
    PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(Properties.Resources).GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(Bitmap)).ToArray();
    Bitmap[] images = new Bitmap[props.Length];
    names = new String[props.Length];
    for(Int32 i = 0; i < props.length; i++)
    {
        images[i] = prop.GetValue(null, null) as Bitmap;
        names[i] = prop.Name;
    }
    return images;
}
```

Calling code:

```
String[] picNames;
Bitmap[] cards = GetResourceImages(out picNames);
```